# How much does the Top 1% have?

Tags: statistics

Please consider the following problem and my answer to it. The answer seems to low to me. Is my answer right?
Thanks,
Bob

Problem:
The median net worth of a certain population is $97K$. To be in the top $5\%$ you need to have a net
worth of $2387K$. Assuming the population follows the Pareto distribution, what is the minimum net
worth you need to be in top $1\%$?
Answer:
For the Pareto distribution we have:
\begin{eqnarray*}
P(X > x) &=& \Big( \frac{x}{x_m}  \Big) ^ \alpha \\
\end{eqnarray*}
The above formula assumes that $x$ is greater than $0$. Now, we need to find the two parameters
$x_m$ and $\alpha$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\Big( \frac{97}{x_m}  \Big) ^ \alpha &=& 0.5 \\
\Big( \frac{2387}{x_m}  \Big) ^ \alpha &=& 0.95 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Using software, I find:
\begin{eqnarray*}
x_m &=& 3083 \\
\alpha &=& 0.200386 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now we have our model.
\begin{eqnarray*}
0.99 &=& \Big( \frac{x}{x_m}  \Big) ^ \alpha \\
0.99 &=& \Big( \frac{x}{3083}  \Big) ^  {0.200386}\\
0.9510821 &=& \Big( \frac{x}{3083}  \Big) \\
x &=& 3083( 0.9510821 ) \\
x &=& 2932.1861 \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Here is an updated solution:

For the Pareto distribution we have:
\begin{eqnarray*}
P(X > x) &=& \Big( \frac{x_m}{x}  \Big) ^ \alpha \\
\end{eqnarray*}
The above formula assumes that $x$ is greater than $0$. Now, we need to find the two parameters
$x_m$ and $\alpha$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\Big( \frac{x_m}{97}  \Big) ^ \alpha &=& 0.5 \\
\Big( \frac{x_m}{2387}  \Big) ^ \alpha &=& 0.95 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Using software, I find:
\begin{eqnarray*}
x_m &=& 3083.33 \\
\alpha &=& -0.200386 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now we have our model.
\begin{eqnarray*}
0.99 &=& \Big( \frac{x_m}{x}  \Big) ^ \alpha \\
0.99 &=& \Big( \frac{3083.33}{x}  \Big) ^ { -0.200386 } \\
1.010101 &=& \Big( \frac{3083.33}{x}  \Big) ^ { 0.200386 } \\
1.00514339 &=& \Big( \frac{3083.33}{x}  \Big) \\
x &=& 2932.50 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Is this answer right? My feeling is that it is still too low? If so, what did I do wrong?

Comment: I edited your Question: Note how exponents work in JaX. If you type `$y^12$` you get $y^12,$ but if you type `$y^{12}` you get $y^{12}.$

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution) says the CDF is $1 - (x_m/x)^\alpha,$ for $x > x_m,$ so you should check your formula for $P(X > x).$ Another reason to check is that your formula gives probabilities that exceed 1/2.

Suggest correcting your formula, re-estimating parameters, and trying again.

Comment: I believe my formula for $P(X > x)$ is correct. It is consisted with the CDF given in Wikipedia. Actually, I got the formula from Wikipedia.

Comment: In spite of finding $x = 2932.1861 < x_m =3038?$

Comment: I am not saying that my work is correct. In fact, I suspect it is wrong. What I am saying is that I believe my formula for $P(X > x)$ is correct.

Comment: Perhaps sooner or later -- after all else fails -- you will take another look at Wikipedia to fix your mistake.

Comment: I have $\frac{x}{x_m}$ and it should be $\frac{x_m}{x}$. I will fix the post.